# how to save wp_editor html content in options table

Tags: plugin-development, customization, wp-editor, options

```
 wp_editor( $default_content, $editor_id,array('textarea_name' => $option_name,'media_buttons' => false,'editor_height' => 350,'teeny' => true)  );
   submit_button('Save', 'primary');
```

I want to create a mail template where admin can change content and put shortcode where he wants.

created a form and wrote the code above but when I click on save it not save the HTML formatted content.

please help any one

Comment: the first step is to create a form with a textarea. and when saving the text of this textarea works, just add the call to `wp_editor`.

Comment: @mmm can you send me code how to implement it

Comment: You have not explain how you want to use this. Edit your question to add more details.

Comment: I want to design dynamic email template in admin where he can change content and design it accordingly

Comment: You need to register the settings field and such. You can read up on the [WordPress Settings API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API)

Comment: @Cedon can you please share code with me how to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo '<form action="" class="booked-settings-form" method="post">';
$default_content='<p>Mail formate</p>';
$editor_id = 'customerCleanerMail';
$option_name='customerCleanerMail';
$default_content=html_entity_decode($default_content);
$default_content=stripslashes($default_content);
wp_editor( $default_content, $editor_id,array('textarea_name' => $option_name,'media_buttons' => false,'editor_height' => 350,'teeny' => true)  );
submit_button('Save', 'primary');   echo '</form>';
if(isset($_POST['customerCleanerMail'])  ){
      $var2=htmlentities(wpautop($_POST['customerCleanerMail']));
      $fff=update_option('customerCleanerMail', $var2);
}
```

In form section i used wp_editor with his options, wp_editor
 work like html editor but when you store these data it not storing
html data. so we found solution how to store html data wpautop() and
htmlentities() both two functions help to store html formated data

Answer (score -1):

Very simple

if (isset($_POST[$editor_id])){
    update_option('name_option_you_want', $editor_id);
}

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?